# How to get the index of the EDT type array elements? [Dynamics AX development]

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

My program was trying to loop through one AOT Form and grab labels of all its controls. Some controls are EDT array type with different labels in each array element.

```
public str labelDefined([int arrayEntry])
```

can retrieve the label of a specific index. But I don't want to hard code the index and want a way that I can get the array index of the EDT array through a method call or something.

I was thinking to define a global counter to work with this - so every time when the loop hit the EDT array element then the counter will increase by 1, and the counter will be set to 0 after traversing through all the elements in the EDT array.

The way I tried to define a global counter is like: 
`#define.index(0)` and then increment the counter by `#define.index(#index + 1)` but it does not quite work for me.

I am pretty new to X++ development any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that there is no logical reason for looping over all controls of a form nor manually looking for labels. Anyway, if you really want to do this, you can use the **DictEnum** System Class

Example: http://www.jaestevan.com/ax-tip-exportar-valores-de-un-enumerado-en-microsoft-dynamics-ax